# Unity Desktop and 18.04: Get Workspace Preview feature which 16.04 had

Tags: unity, compiz, workspaces

Unity on Ubuntu 16.04 has a nice feature. When switching among workspaces, the switcher preview dims the other workspaces to highlight the current workspace.

However on Ubuntu 18.04 this feature does not work for the background.

[Ubuntu 16.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjvkv.png)
[Ubuntu 18.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVkEU.png)

Both screenshots above are taken on fresh installations after manually installing `ubuntu-unity-desktop` (only for Ubuntu 18.04) and `compizconfig-settings-manager` and after increasing the virtual desktop size to 4x4.

A dist-upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 yields the same fault.

How can I activate this helpful effect?

Answer (score 0):

the last 5 years I worked with Ubuntu 16.04 and I really enjoyed it.
Now after it's LTS is over I installed a new Ubuntu 20.04 together with unity desktop.
But then I also faced this missing feature of highlighted workspaces in the quick switcher using Keyboard shortcuts [Ctrl + Alt + ArrowKeys].
If there are open windows, in the preview they are brighter for the selected instance.
But you don't see a difference when you navigate over empty workspaces.
Using [Super+S] the currently selected workspace is marked with a border around it (that's how it should also look like for the quick switcher, as it did for ubuntu 16.04).

Are there any news about the original question?
I am used to have a large workspace grid and the navigation over empty ones of them is sometimes very confusing now.

Thanks for every tip about that topic!

BR Daniel